# UICollectionView Items are offsetting by its section position

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have implemented `UICollectionView` for rendering `WKWebview` as contentView's subview of `UICollectionViewCell` and bound UIPageControl to it.

> Note: Just for demoing the problem while rendering, I have made the size of the cell width as `100`

Problem is first Webview(Which is a cell in the first section of collection view) is showing as expected but the second cell displaying with an offset of cell width.

UICollectionViewDelegate Override methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // set this width for just showing screenshot for this question 
    return CGSize(100, height: view.frame.height-view.safeAreaInsets.top);
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.webviewsPageControl.currentPage = indexPath.section;
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    self.webviewsPageControl.numberOfPages = self.webviews?.count ?? 0;
    return self.webviews?.count ?? 0;
}
```

[image]

For identification, I made the UICollectionViewCell background as red.

So the question is, how to remove the offset so that webviews can be rendered side by side. And Why is this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the minimumLineSpacing = 0 on the flow layout, e.g.

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

Comment: Tried this, But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to reduce spacing between columns:

`let cellsPerRow = 2 //number of columns or number of cells in each row`

In viewDidLoad():

```
guard let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0 //setting margin between cell columns = 0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0// setting margin between cell lines = 0
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) //Not required, solutions works without it as well
```

Finally,

```
//function to set number of columns
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let marginsAndInsets = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right + flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
        let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }
```